# Javascript OnClick Function not Working (with partial code in head)

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, web

I was renovating my website while I came across this error.
It is a simple username-password Javascript calling function.

Here is the code (because of confidentiality I would not like to give out any usernames, passwords, links, or function names):

```
<head>
<script>
function ----() { 
var username = prompt("Please enter your username.");
if (username.toLowerCase() == "-----"){
    var password = prompt("Please enter your password.");
    if (password.toLowerCase() == "-----"){
   window.open('http://example.com',"_self")
}
else{
alert('Incorrect password. Please try again.')
}
}
else{
alert('Incorrect username. Please try again.')
}
}
</script>
</head>  

<body>
<p><a onclick="----()" href="javascript:void(0);">------</a></p>
</body>
```

Please don't criticize my code; I've only been coding for 1~2 years. I would love to learn more from this renovating experience!

Thanks!
Jefferson Yu

Comment: Anybody who views your site could observe these function names, usernames, and passwords in your code. This isn't secure at all.

Comment: I know that this isn't very secure, but it will be okay because this code will be used for a casual purpose, not a serious website.

Answer (score 0):

> You have redundant else statements. I have added a sample function called foo to explain. Try to adapt indentation in your code, that will save you from creating syntactical errors.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function foo() { 
    var username = prompt("Please enter your username.");
    if (username.toLowerCase() == "user"){
        var password = prompt("Please enter your password.");
        if (password.toLowerCase() == "pass"){
            window.open('http://example.com',"_self");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Incorrect password. Please try again.');
    }
}
</script>
</head>  
<body>
<p><a onclick="foo()" href="javascript:void(0);">click me</a></p>
</body>enter code here
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... you can try it links on www.dsandb.weebly.com/login.html

Comment: Could you please help me find a quick and effective solution to this problem?